# Projection makes query slower

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have over 600k of record in MongoDb.
my user Schema looks like this:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId,
    "password" : String,
    "email" : String,
    "location" : Object,
    "followers" : Array,
    "following" : Array,
    "dateCreated" : Number,
    "loginCount" : Number,
    "settings" : Object,
    "roles" : Array,
    "enabled" : Boolean,
    "name" : Object
}
```

following query:

```js
db.users.find(
     {},
     { 
         name:1, 
         settings:1,
         email:1,
         location:1
     }
).skip(656784).limit(10).explain()
```

results into this:

```js
{
    "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 10,
    "nscannedObjects" : 656794,
    "nscanned" : 656794,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 656794,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 656794,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 5131,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 1106,
    "server" : "shreyance:27017",
    "filterSet" : false
}
```

and after removing projection same query `db.users.find().skip(656784).limit(10).explain()`

results into this:

```js
{
    "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 10,
    "nscannedObjects" : 656794,
    "nscanned" : 656794,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 656794,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 656794,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 5131,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 209,
    "server" : "shreyance:27017",
    "filterSet" : false
}
```

As far I know projection always increase performance of a query. So I am unable to understand why MongoDB is behaving like this. Can someone explain this. And when to use projection and when not. And how actually projection is implemented in MongoDB.

Comment: Do you get these results repeatedly? The second query might be faster just because data is cached (loaded in memory) from the first query.

Comment: Because it is applying the projection to 656794 documents

Comment: but why it is applying the projection to 656794 documents it is very wrong implementation. I need only 10 records so projection should be applied to only 10 documents

Comment: @Messa Yes I get thes results repeatedly.

Comment: Hmm as a small test if you take the skip out what results do you get?

Comment: I it certainly faster, query with projection take 6 ms and without projection 0 ms, but still it should not apply projection to 656794 documents

Comment: Sorry, nvm. Hmm, there is most likely some clause here that prevents it logically from skipping the _id index to the point that it should return

Comment: youve made an assumption that the second query was faster because of projection.  likely it was faster because it was run second and the data was in ram

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky he does say: "Yes I get thes results repeatedly."

Comment: @Stennie MongoDB 2.6.3

Comment: @AsyaKamsky I also tried the second query first. Same results though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct that projection makes this skip query slower in MongoDB 2.6.3. This is related to an optimisation issue with the 2.6 query planner tracked as [SERVER-13946](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13946).

The 2.6 query planner (as at 2.6.3) is adding SKIP (and LIMIT) stages after projection analysis, so the projection is being unnecessarily applied to results that get thrown out during the skip for this query. I tested a similar query in MongoDB 2.4.10 and the `nScannedObjects` was equal to the number of results returned by my `limit` rather than `skip + limit`.

There are several factors contributing to your query performance:

1) You haven't specified any query criteria (`{}`), so this query is doing a collection scan in [natural order](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/natural/) rather than using an index.

2) The query cannot be covered because there is no projection.

3) You have an extremely large `skip` value of 656,784.

There is definitely room for improvement on the query plan, but I wouldn't expect skip values of this magnitude to be reasonable in normal usage. For example, if this was an application query for pagination with 50 results per page your `skip()` value would be the equivalent of page number 13,135.

Comment: Indeed this skip is not feasible but it is a good find, hopefully this  will be fixed soon as it can mean even small skips have to do extra work than needed

Answer (score 3):

Unless the result of your projection does something to produce an "index only" query, and that means only the the fields "projected" in the result are **all** present in the index only, then you are **always** producing **more** work for the query engine.

You have to consider the process:

1. How do I match? On document or index? Find appropriate primary or other index.
2. Given the index, scan and find things.
3. Now what do I have to return? Is **all** of the data in the index? If not go back to the collection and pull the documents.

That is the basic process. So unless one of those stages "optimizes" in any way then of course things "take longer".

You need to look at this as designing a "server engine" and understand the steps that need to be undertaken. Considering none of your conditions met anything that would produce "optimal" on the specified steps you need to learn to accept that.

Your "best" case, is wher **only** the projected fields are the fields present in the chosen index. But really, even that has the overhead of loading the index.

So choose wisely, and understand the constraints and memory requirements for what you are writing our query for. That is what "optimization" is all about.

Comment: I don't think this explains why MongoDB looks like it is projecting for the 656784 documents it can count with an _id index

Comment: @NeilLunn I understood your point. But I agree with Sammaye also 'why mongo is applying projection to every document' it should apply projection only to returning documents

Comment: @ShreyanceJain The **longer** explanation of what "projection" actually is in the context of where this is not "index only" and therefore "picking" from fields in the index actually needs an understanding of the `$project` operator from the aggregation framework pipeline and understanding the query engine processing. Essentially you are otherwise asking to "pass though" all of your documents and "re-shape". Does this need further explanation?

Comment: Sorry by count I actually mean traverse, MongoDB is able to traverse the btree to the point of the skip. That is what you actually miss out